# Is there any way to find which process utilizing swap memory in Linux OS?

Tags: linux

A Linux node with 125GB of RAM and swap memory defined is 6GB, swappiness is 30.

In the last few days noticed that swap usage reached up to 4.8GB. swap could be the reason for application performance issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> could be the reason for application performance issue?

Could be, yes... but we can't really say more without further information.

---

> Is there any way to find which process utilizing swap memory in Linux OS?

I use the following pipeline to show information about each process that is using swap:

```
grep '^VmSwap:' /proc/*/status \
    | grep -v '0 kB$' \
    | sed -re 's#^/proc/([0-9]+)/status:VmSwap:[ \t]+([0-9]+) kB$#\1 \2#' \
    | sort -nrk2 \
    | while read pid swap; do \
        printf "%10s kB    %-6s    " ${swap} ${pid}; \
        cat /proc/${pid}/cmdline | xargs -0 | fold -sw160 | sed -re '/^$/d; 1!s/^/\t\t\t\t/;'; \
      done \
    | less -cRS
```

The output looks like this (usage, PID, command line):

```
233256 kB    31326     mysqld
 24968 kB    32424     /usr/local/bin/ruby bin/rails server -b 0.0.0.0
 17232 kB    15256     /usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock
  8972 kB    15405     /usr/lib/virtualbox/VBoxHeadless --startvm acdb10c9-00fa-4514-a836-b9e3554214f3
  8664 kB    14551     /usr/bin/containerd
  5972 kB    22984     /usr/sbin/named -f -u bind -c /etc/bind/named.conf
[...]
```

- `grep '^VmSwap:' /proc/*/status`

  - `/proc/*/status` is documented [here](https://linux.die.net/man/5/proc) - the line starting `VmSwap:` indicates how much swap space the process is using.
- `grep -v '0 kB$'`

  - Ignore processes that are not using swap
- `sed -re 's#^/proc/([0-9]+)/status:VmSwap:[ \t]+([0-9]+) kB$#\1 \2#'`

  - Cut out the PID and size information
- `sort -nrk2`

  - Sort by numeric, reverse order on key 2 (i.e: swap usage)
- `printf "%10s kB    %-6s    " ${swap} ${pid}`

  - Format the first two columns of the output
- `cat /proc/${pid}/cmdline | xargs -0 | fold -sw160 | sed -re '/^$/d; 1!s/^/\t\t\t\t/;'`

  - Get the process' command line
  - Fold it to 160 characters
  - Delete empty lines, and
  - Add indentation to additional lines
- `less -cRS`

  - Present it using `less` for easy review

Answer (score 1):

Yes, swapping could well be the culprit.

Run "top" to see a list of processes and the resources they are using.  Similarly, use vmstat to check how much swap is.happening. If its a lot try  lower vm.swapiness further - maybe to 5.

Answer (score 0):

`ps -e v`
will give you vm stats for all processes.  It will tell you how many page faults each process has generated.

Comment: how it will tell which process is actually the culprit?